# Android relative canvas scaling (depending on an offset)

Tags: android, zooming, android-canvas, android-drawable

I draw items on my canvas with scaling and adding offset (for dragging)

Rects are drawn with top, left, right and bottom multiplied by scale value and added offset, for example `left = defaultLeft * scale + offsetX`

When scale is changed, rects move outta view zone, because the offset is not dependent on scale.

I need a function that will calculate the offset delta needed to keep the content in view zone like it is done in map apps